# What is this tensor called?

Tags: tensors

Is there a standard name for this "generalized identity" tensor

$x^{i j k ...} = I(i = j = k = ...)$

where $I$ is the indicator function, ie the tensor is 1 when all indexes are equal & zero otherwise.

I would also like to know how this tensor is usually treated in the Penrose graphical notation or tensor/string diagrams. Is there a standard symbol and a canonical set of diagrammatic rules that define it.

Comment: Kronecker delta doesn't suffice?  $\delta^{ijk} = \delta^{ij}\delta^{jk}$, etc.

Comment: @Sammy Black I have only seen Kronecker delta used to refer to matrices and distributions and according to Wikipedia the generalized Kronecker delta is something else. If it is commonly used for the higher dimensional tensors then that is the answer I am looking for. I am still looking for the Penrose notation treatment of the higher dimensional cases.

Comment: Such a symbol will not be a tensor. Will be just a symbol. You can see this by writing the same expression in other coordinate system: it will not retain its properties.